# Problem using unique_together and saving authenticated user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, unique-constraint

There is a problem in my code for two fields entry uniqueness checking.

I defined a model with `unique_together` to check uniqueness of a field records for each user, but it accepts duplicated entry added by that user.

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserItem(models.Model):
    definer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    .
    .
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("definer", "item_name")
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView

class RecordCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = UserItem
    template_name = 'item_new.html'
    #excluding "definer" field and inserting its value by form_valid
    fields = ['item_name', . . .]   

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.definer = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I expect warning and preventing users to add new record with the same "item_name" added before by themselves, but it accepts them (without warning).

When I replace "definer" with other fields, it works fine and warns for duplicate records. Additionally when records added by admin, it works and there will be the expected warning.

I guess, this problem is for that the authenticated user is inserted as "definer" by "def form_valid" after the "unique_together = ("definer", "item_name")" has done its role. On the other hand, uniqueness checking in done when the "definer" is empty.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Edit: Adding full model

`````
```` Full Model in model.py
class UserItem(models.Model):
    item_type = models.CharField(max_length=12, verbose_name='Item type')
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bound = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, default=None, max_length=4, verbose_name='Bound')
    price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    maximum_use = models.FloatField(default=0, verbose_name='Maximum use (%)’)
    matterial = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None, verbose_name='matterial (%)')
    energy = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None, verbose_name='energy (kcal/k)')

    definer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}, name: {}, definer: {}".format(self.item_type, self.item_name, self.definer,)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profile')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("definer", "item_name")
````


```` views.py after @Pedro suggestion to edit
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class RecordCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = UserItem
    template_name = 'item_new.html'
    fields = ['item_name', 'matterial', 'energy',]

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('profile')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user_item = form.save(commit=False)
        user_item.definer = self.request.user
        user_item.item_type = 'required'
        user_item.bound = 'min'
        try:
            user_item.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            form.add_error('item_name', 'Item name is repeated')
            return self.form_invalid(form)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
````
`````

Comment: If you have migrated the constraint to the database with `makemigrations` and `migrate` (check if the constraint is present in the database if you can), constraint violations are impossible. It is possible to create model instances that violate the constraint, but it's not possible to save them. So do some more digging on what exactly is happening. The constraint is not the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing in this line ```form.instance.definer = self.request.user```, if you are using a create view you don't have an instance. Can you explain?

Comment: @Pedro I'm a beginner and have no form.py file in this app, I got this pattern (including instance) from similar codes in books (Django for Beginners, Learn Web Development with Django 2.0) and webpages. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are adding the `definer` after the form is validated. You can pass the `request.user` as the initial data, like this:

```
class RecordCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = UserItem
    template_name = 'item_new.html'
    #excluding "definer" field and inserting its value by form_valid
    fields = ['item_name', 'definer', ...]

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['definer'] = self.request.user
        return initial
```

Now you don't need to override `form_valid`.

**Edit:** If you don't want the `definer` in the form fields you can do this:

```
class RecordCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = UserItem
    template_name = 'item_new.html'
    fields = ['item_name', ...]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user_item = form.save(commit=False)
        user_item.definer = self.request.user
        try:
            user_item.save()  # should raise an exception if unique_together constrain fails
        except ValidationError:
            form.add_error('item_name', 'Item name is repeated')  # add custom error to form
            return self.form_invalid(form)  # return the invalid form
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: Thanks Pedro, this solves current problem but introduced another; the user can select other users a the "definer" value, because the "definer" field has options including all registered users.

Comment: @mkiani I added an alternative solution, notice you don't need to override the ```get_initial``` method.

Comment: Thanks for edition, I used this too, but there was no success and the duplicates are accepted from a user.

Comment: @mkiani can you post your full model

Comment: @mkiani also did you run ```makemigrations``` and ```migrate``` after adding the constrain to your model?

Comment: I added full model, Also I did migration.

Comment: @mkiani did you try again after migrating?

Comment: Yes, certainly I did it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Pedro's very helpful hints; Lastly I could solve my problem by some changes in his code.

Also I removed this part in model.py:
"class meta:
    unique_together = ("definer", "item_name")"

`````
````views.py
class RecordCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = UserItem
    template_name = 'item_new.html'
    fields = ['item_name', 'matterial', 'energy',]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user_items = form.save(commit=False)
        item_name = user_items.item_name
        qs = UserItemComposition.objects.filter(definer=self.request.user, item_name=item_name)
        if qs.exists():
            form.add_error('item_name', 'Item name is repeated')
            return self.form_invalid(form)
        form.instance.definer = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
````
`````